# List manager that is driven by code

Tags: list-manager

I know that List Manager is just a filtered lookup xDB contacts. But is it possible to create a list that has custom c# pipelines. That could call out to an API and returns an IEnumerable of email addresses?

Comment: How would you expect to use this list?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich like normal. Send an EXM email to the people in the list.

Comment: List Manager doesnt deal with Email Addresses. It deals with Contacts. Contacts happen to have data that include an email address (the piece that EXM uses), but List Manager only cares about Contacts. You can use a Custom Rule to filter contacts, that then gets turned into a Segment for List Manager to "generate" lists on the fly.

Comment: @PeteNavarra I agree, but i am lookin to make EXM fire off emails based on a list of emails that are dynamic and do not have contacts associated to them.

Comment: EXM won't be able to do that, without heavy and significant changes to ALOT of EXM. EXM requires the Contact Identifier, not email addresses.  As it also fires interactions against the contact.

Comment: Thanks @PeteNavarra   I will gone back to adding facet data to my contacts to create my list. It’s a lot of heavy lifting up accomplish a small task. But it is what it is.

Comment: A lot of comments were added while I was writing my answer :D Anyway, @PeteNavarra said the same I wanted to describe.

Comment: Chris, thinking outside the box here, if essentially all you want to do is "import contacts via excel file", you might be able to deconstruct that process and inject an API, and just create arbitary contacts that mean nothing except for an email address, where the source is an API instead of csv, but that would take some doing.  You might also be able to treat your API as a CRM and use DEF to sync contacts as well

Comment: DEF is a good idea. I think in the end, I will have to continue to use facets. The email addresses I want to send are real contacts. But they are people who are owners of an asset. So this year 100 people own 64 assets. Next year it might be 120 different people owing 75 assets. So it really changes. I will need to clean all contacts of a certain facet. And then reset the facet. So it would be accurate for a moment. And then I can use events to update the facets in real time. Lots to think about.

Answer (score 4):

I spent some time to have a look deeper at the List Management tool. Finally I didn't find a way how we can "inject" custom code to load "external" list of email address.

But anyway, even if you find a way how to implement it, in my point of view, we have a few reasons why it is not a good idea:

- As you mentioned in the question, Sitecore List is not really a list of address, it is a list of Contacts;
- When you choose lists during setting up an EXM email campaign, you don't assign email addresses for the campaign, you just assign list ids for it. Contacts populating happens during dispatching process;
- EXM expects contacts as a source or target for sending emails. It extends a links with a keys built based on the contact id. It allows EXM to track clicks, opens and another events associated with email. But if you decided somehow to use independent email addresses, you will definitely lose an ability using all power of EXM email analytic.

Finally, I had the following ideas how to achieve your goal. I haven't found a solution, maybe you will:

- I thought we can implement custom List Provider, but I didn't find a configuration which allows us to load it. So I didn't find any List Provider at all;
- Lists have sources. I though we can "inject" something as a source for a list, but I also didn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it seems a lot like you want the ability to update the target list at will.

It is possible to [add/remove contacts to a specific list](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-list-manager-api.html#UUID-7489bb7d-fcd0-a8da-c368-0e69705baf34_section-idm45679422144528_body). At what point to do so would depends on your application, it might be as asset owner changes are saved or during some kind of sync with an external store.